# Loading csv and saving HDF5 in Python

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, pytables, h5py

I'm trying to import data from a text file (three columns of floats, 65341 rows, delimited by one or more spaces), and save it to an HDF5 file.  I'm trying to save them in a table which is a child of three groups, defined by the filename.

So, for a file called 'data_a1_b2_c3.dat' I want a 1x6000 array in /data/a1/b2/c3  (where c3 is the table)

I can create the HDF5 file, and the groups, but creating the table is proving a problem.

This is what I've come up with so far (I've left out the filename parsing and error checking; that works):

```
import numpy as np
import tables as tb

# load datafile
fname = 'data_a1_b2_c3.dat'
data=np.genfromtxt(fname)
data=data[:,2]  

# Open hdf5 file
h5=tb.openFile("h5file.h5",'a')


gp1 = h5.create_group(h5.root,"data")
gp2 = h5.create_group(gp1,"a1")
gp3 = h5.create_group(gp2,"b2")

t = h5.create_table(gp3,"c3",data,'my data')
```

That last line throws an error as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/tables/file.py", line 1067, in create_table
    chunkshape=chunkshape, byteorder=byteorder)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/tables/table.py", line 842, in __init__
    descr_from_dtype(nparray.dtype)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/tables/description.py", line 759, in descr_from_dtype
    for name in dtype_.names:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

My first thought that it's something to do with my data array.  However, I'm new to Python, and the SciPi documentation site is currently down (anyone have a mirror?!) (http://www.isup.me/http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/)

The shape of my array looks odd, but the type looks about right.  Any thoughts?

```
>>> data.shape
(65341,)
>>> data.dtype
dtype('float64')
```

For info, here's the first three rows of the data file I'm importing (only need the third column)

```
  0.250000000000000       0.250000000000000        584.469683289793     
  0.250000000000000        1.00000000000000        840.153369718130     
  0.250000000000000        2.00000000000000        821.242731813009
```

Comment: You can sometimes find cached versions of web pages by searching for the URL on http://www.cachedpages.com/. Here is a [archived snapshot of docs.scipy.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20140703133801/http://docs.scipy.org/doc/) as of 2014-7-3.

Comment: I am pretty sure the issue here is that data is a ndarray and the examples for using pytables all uses classes or recarrays.  (http://pytables.github.io/usersguide/tutorials.html)  If you are using pytables elsewhere keep plugging, otherwise the h5py interface is not too hard to use alone.http://docs.h5py.org/en/2.3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a quick win - you can save your data as an array (which I guess it is - since data is just 1D):

```
a = h5.create_array(gp3,"c3",data,'my data')
```

Remember to do a file close as well:

```
h5.close()
```

Results in:

[image: array result]

If you really want to save it as a table, you basically have to remember that tables need to be **defined** first (in terms of their record structure) and then their values assigned and flushed.

So, just what you were doing except add this to the start:

```
class Data(tb.IsDescription):
  value = tb.Float32Col()
```

and then do:

```
t = h5.create_table(gp3,"c3",Data,'my data')

row = t.row
for d in data:
   row['value'] = d
   row.append()
t.flush()
```

Results in:

[image: table]

Finally, personally I would actually use [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html) for this CSV to HDF5 stuff - far easier to manipulate DataFrames and Series...